# Try to exit while looping in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to exit the loop after the user puts the correct input. Instead it keeps saying "try again". I want it to say finally got it after they guess the right number (33)

```
x = input ('guess a number between 0 to 100 \n ')
q = 33
if x > q :
    print ('your number is to high')
if x == q :
    print 'you have guessed right'
if x < q :
   print 'your number is to low'

while x != 33 :
    p = input ('try again \n')
    if p == 33 :
        print 'you finally got it'
```

Comment: You need to show us your code if you want us to help you.

Comment: just do, x = input('Guess a number between 0 and 100, or STOP to quit'). if x == 'STOP': break in your while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exit a loop, just use `break`. Your code would look like:

```
x = input ('guess a number between 0 to 100 \n ')
q = 33
if x > q :
    print ('your number is to high')
if x == q :
    print 'you have guessed right'
if x < q :
   print 'your number is to low'

while x != 33 :
    p = input ('try again \n')
    if p == 33 :
        print 'you finally got it'
        break
```

The break at the end does everything you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `break` to exit the loop when the user puts the correct input.

eg :

```
if var == 5:
   break
```

Answer (score 1):

When you changed the variable to p, the entire while loop became incorrect. It works, but when printing "try again" after the first guess, it's referring to the first value entered, not the most recent guess. This is the correct way:

```
x = input ('guess a number between 0 to 100 \n ')
q = 33
if x > q :
print ('your number is too high')
if x == q :
    print 'you have guessed right'
if x < q :
   print 'your number is too low'

while x != 33 :
    x = input ('try again \n')
print("you finally got it")
```